# Parent View of UITextField in UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uialertcontroller

I have a UITextField in a UIAlertController and I have no idea how to access its parent view to change the background color. In the screen shot, it's the white box just behind the "Student name" text field.

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: this will be a hacky way to do and i would avoid and probably use a custom alert library from github. UIAlertController can be updated by apple and your app might break

Comment: That's what I'm going to have to do. I did it like this for MVP but if a library is unavoidable then I'll have to go that route.

Comment: It seems like you are running up against the limitations of standard UIKit controls. Going custom comes at a cost (initial dev time, maintenance, potential departure from HIGs) but is sometimes the right decision. If it's really necessary I'd recommend using something like `NYAlertViewController` as a starting point.

Comment: @KyleClegg thanks for the tip!